# Nesting Invoke-Command for clustered hosts and virtual machines

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-remoting

I've ran into a problem whereby I'm trying run commands on a VM which is listed on one of two nodes as part of a Windows Failover Cluster.

```
$computers = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\PS Scripts\References\IPList.csv' -Delimiter ","
$localCred = Get-Credential -Message "Local credentials required" -UserName Administrator
$domainCred = Get-Credential -Message "Local credentials required" -UserName Domain\Administrator
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Invoke-Command -Computer $computer.Host -Credential $domainCred -ScriptBlock {
        Invoke-Command -VMName $Using:computer.VMName -Credential $Using:localCred -ScriptBlock {
            New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $Using:computer.IPAddress -PrefixLength $Using:computer.PrefixLength -AddressFamily $Using:computer.AddressFamily -InterfaceAlias $Using.computer.InterfaceAlias -DefaultGateway $Using:computer.DefaultGateway
}}}
```

As these are local variables, I would need to declare these as remote variables within the Invoke-Command script block.

If I were to run the above command without nesting the two invoke-commands, then the script runs without issues.

Is this the correct way of performing this task? I've never had to nest Invoke-Command statements before, but perhaps there is a better way of doing it. I'm declaring the **$Using** variable.

When the script runs, the following error occurs:

**Cannot bind argument to parameter 'IPAddress' because it is an empty string.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-NetIPAddress], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,New-NetIPAddress**

Answer (score 0):

From [about Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.3#the-using-scope-modifier) (emphasis mine):

> For any script or command that executes out of session, you need the Using scope modifier to embed variable values from the **calling session scope**, so that out of session code can access them.

This means that the inner `$Using:computer` only looks in the scope of the surrounding `Invoke-Command` for variable `$computer`, which doesn't exist.

To solve the problem, create a local variable `$computer1` before the inner `Invoke-Command`:

```sh
$computers = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\PS Scripts\References\IPList.csv' -Delimiter ","
$localCred = Get-Credential -Message "Local credentials required" -UserName Administrator
$domainCred = Get-Credential -Message "Local credentials required" -UserName Domain\Administrator
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Invoke-Command -Computer $computer.Host -Credential $domainCred -ScriptBlock {
        $computer1 = $using:computer
        Invoke-Command -VMName $Using:computer.VMName -Credential $Using:localCred -ScriptBlock {
            New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $Using:computer1.IPAddress -PrefixLength $Using:computer1.PrefixLength -AddressFamily $Using:computer1.AddressFamily -InterfaceAlias $Using.computer1.InterfaceAlias -DefaultGateway $Using:computer1.DefaultGateway
}}}
```

I've named the variable `$computer1` so you can see better which variable the `$using:` refers to, but you could even name it `$computer` as well.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I've tried this and now I'm getting another error (Cannot bind argument to parameter 'IPAddress' because it is an empty string.)

Comment: I've had another look and tried to run this again with your code, and it's now showing an error regarding the local variable (Invoke-Command : The value of the using variable '$using:computer1' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set in the loc
al session.) Do you have any other ideas to correct this please?

Comment: @Avtech To be honest, I've never used nested `Invoke-Command` before, but from what I've read the code should work. Alternatively try to pass `$computer` via `-ArgumentList` like this: `Invoke-Command -VMName $Using:computer.VMName -Credential $Using:localCred -ArgumentList $using:computer -ScriptBlock { New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $args.IPAddress …`